# Como redirecionar para uma outra página, utilizando o query que foi para a página anterior?

Tags: javascript, express.js

Estou com uma aplicação que quando a pessoa se cadastra, ela joga para uma página e depois de 3,5s ele redireciona para a outra página, mas eu queria que ele redirecionasse com o query que eu preciso, para já aparecer a pessoa cadastrada.

**Código da parte que redireciona para a página de sucesso de cadastro:**

```
const db = await Database
    await createProffy(db, { proffyValue, classValue, classScheduleValues })

    let queryString = "?subject=" + req.body.subject
    queryString += "&weekday=" + req.body.weekday[0]
    queryString += "&time=" + req.body.time_from[0]


    return res.redirect('/success-proffy' + queryString)
```

**A página vem com aquele query lá em cima, conforme abaixo:**

[image: print da primeira tela de sucesso]

**Depois de 3,5 segundos ele redireciona para a pagina study:**

```
<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.href = '/study'
    }, 3500)
  </script>
```

preciso que o query vá para essa página do study também, assim como foi para a do sucesso.

OBS.: esse setTimeOut está direto no HTML da página de sucesso!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `window.location.search`.

Se a url atual for:
`http://foo.com/success-proffy?subject=FOO&weekday=1&time=32132132`

o window.location.search deve retornar:
`?subject=FOO&weekday=1&time=32132132`

```
<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        location.href = '/study' + window.location.search
    }, 3500)
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Lucas, funcionou perfeitamente, você é fera!!

Comment: só não esquece de marcar a pergunta como respondida

Answer (score 0):

Não há como você fazer nenhuma operação pelo servidor após o `res` ter sido enviado. A solução é só pelo browser mesmo

```
<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.href = `/study${location.search}`
    }, 3500)
</script>
```

EDIT: essa operação é mais segura com o `search` que o colega citou, já que se não houver querystring retorna `""` ao contrário de slice -1